# What counts as querying the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I do:

```
const table = document.getElementById('table1');
```

and then

```
const cell = table.rows.item(1).cells.item(1);
```

Am I querying the DOM in the second operation?

Comment: That code doesn't execute - [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (which is what [`table.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) is) doesn't have a `find` method - so no.

Comment: sure, if `table.rows.find` was function

Comment: "*counts as querying the DOM*" - in what context?

Comment: Sorry. I meant 'item', not 'find'. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any variations of `Node.childNodes` or `Node.parentNode` etc. does query the DOM.

The Node objects we have access to in the JS world are just a wrapper object over an actual DOM object. These wrapper objects don't contain all the links to the DOM tree, all they do is to expose getter functions that will call internal DOM methods to "query the DOM".

So even the line throwing a TypeError (because you probably confused `item` with `find`)

```
const cell = table.rows.find(1).cells.find(1);
```

will query the DOM from the `.rows` getter.

However the simple access to the variable `table` didn't query the DOM, you did store the wrapper object, which kept a reference to the underlying DOM object.

Note that one exception are "named elements" (the ones with an `id`), which are stored in a Map directly accessible on the Window object and thus to JS. So actually, in the first line you didn't query the DOM.

Now, does this ever matter? Not really, moreover with how fast engines are today.

Comment: Re "*…in the first line you didn't query the DOM*". Modern browsers no doubt have many optimisations to pre–index and store elements in an optimised structure so picking on one particular case where that might occur doesn't really highlight an exception, e.g. there are various properties and collections associated with elements like *document* such as *document.body* and with tables such as headers, footers, bodies, rows, also form controls, etc. Also element IDs as global variables isn't guaranteed. :-)

Comment: @RobG yes [it is guaranteed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), and yes all "modern" browsers do this.(\[edit] had the wrong link, fixed now.)

Comment: `let foo;` will override any DOM element with ID foo, so no, not guaranteed. There's a note at your link: "*As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time…*".

Comment: It is guaranteed that the browser did save it in a map. That's all the point here. + `let` is actually not the best example, because window.foo would still be that element ;) And yes, I never advocated for the use of window.[id] as a mean to access elements, I just pointed out that getElementById is actually not querying the DOM.

Comment: Which is my point, there are many DOM objects and properties that are stored in maps/indexes/whatever. Finding any of them in whatever structure they're stored in likely qualifies as "querying the DOM". :-)